# Is there any way to ignore column of an entity from cassandra database with .net driver

Tags: c#, linq, cassandra

I am working on a .net core project and using cassandra as the data store.
I need to ignore a column to store in database, i have seen in EF and in Mongo db as **IgnoreBson** attribute, but i am not able to find solution for cassandra with .net driver using linq.
I have seen the solution for java driver but not for .net driver.
I am following [this link](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/csharp-driver-cassandra-new-mapper-linq-improvements).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define how your entities map to your columns using the `MappingConfiguration`. In case you need to include only specific columns use the option `ExplicitColumns`:

```cs
MappingConfiguration.Global.Define(
   new Map<User>()
      .TableName("users")
      .PartitionKey(u => u.UserId)
      .ExplicitColumns()
      .Column(u => u.UserId, cm => cm.WithName("id")));
```

https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.10/features/components/linq/#configuring-mappings

In case you are using attribute-based mappings, you can set `ExplicitColumns` on the `TableAttribute`:

```cs
[Table("users", ExplicitColumns = true)]
public class User
{
  // ...
}
```

If you want to use most of the properties in your entity, while just ignoring few of them, you can also use `IgnoreAttribute`:

```cs
[Table("users")]
public class User
{
  // ...

  [Ignore]
  public string IgnoreMe { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So i have to map all the columns i need to? i have large amount of columns, i just want to ignore the navigation properties.

Comment: You can also use `IgnoreAttribute`

Comment: what is the namespace for Ignore?

Answer (score 1):

Very simple in EF Core.. You have two options, data annotations or fluent configuration.

Fluent configuration lends itself to “better practises” so i’d lean towards that if possible.. Heres some examples of both methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/included-properties

Comment: this is for SQL database, i am asking for Cassandra, there is no DbContext in cassandra.

Comment: But, you’re using EF Core? EF Core abstracts out the “how” and allows you to use a uniform platform for development. Whether you’re using SQL, MongoDB, SQLite or whatever, EF configuration is still the same.

Comment: That issue changes the context of your question. You asked "How to ignore navigation properties". For that, my answer is correct. The issue relates to there being no support for the database you are trying to use - which is an entirely different issue altogether.

Comment: Please read the question again, i haven't mentioned the navigation properties. i don't have relationships. I have mentioned the technology and libraries i am using, and asked for ignoring a column from cassandra. Not much difficult to understand